# How to check if language transformer function is regular or not?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata, regular-language

### The Question:

A language transformer function $f(L) = \{ssss \ | \ s \in L\}$

Is $f(A)$ regular if A is a regular language?

I don't know how to start solving the question.

Comment: Suppose you have an FSA that recognizes $L$.  Can you construct one that recognizes $f(L)$?

Comment: How do we do that using regular language in general? Normally there are sets of alphabets for us to construct FSA.

Comment: Actually, I misread the problem.  I was thinking $f(L)$ comprised any four strings from L, not the same string repeated $4$ times.  I apologize.  Now I tend to think the answer is "no", because, intuitively, we have to remember which strings we've seen so far, and there may be infinitely many strings in a regular language.  The usual way to prove that a language is not regular is by means of the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Use_of_the_lemma).   Try $L=\{b^na|n\ge0\}$

Comment: Nice, that's what I have tried with from the start. The thing is, is it okay to choose a certain L for proving or can we only start with a general L regular language?

Comment: Yes, the question means, "Is it true that for every regular language $L$, $f(L)$ is also a regular language?" and one counterexample is all you need.

Comment: Very thanks, this is what I need! Just wondering, should we prove that the L (what you are describing) we are using is regular language beforehand, or it's obvious enough that it is a regular language?

Comment: Matter of taste, I would say.  You might just draw the automaton.  It only has $3$ states.  ($2$ states if you use an NFSA.)